# Possible bug in Gazebo GUI after multiple rotations

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to rotate the same model multiple times, the joints appears as times as I rotate the model (see image in the following link).

[Gazebo GUI after multiple rotates](http://snag.gy/Xx526.jpg)

Steps to reproduce:

Add one model with joints

Enable joint view.

Rotate the model multiple times.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1132/possible-bug-in-gazebo-gui-after-multiple-rotations/) by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 305 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, this is a bug. I filed a ticket here:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/464/joint-visualization-broken-when-model

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-02**:
The bug has been fixed in the gazebo trunk and will be included in gazebo 1.5.